# Rotate line through its center given two points

Tags: matlab, algebra

Given a line A with two points (x1, y1) (x2, y2) and another line B with two points (x1_2, y1_2) (x2_2, y2_2).

Now I want to rotate line B at its center until it is parallel to line A.

What I want to know is the coordinates of B (rotated). The length of line B must stay the same.

I did the maths but can't find the mistake. Here is my code:

```
% Line A
x1 = 125.6238;
x2 = 200.9999;  
y1 = 94.2222;
y2 = 211.2726;

% Line B
x1_2 = 133.8045;
x2_2 = 188.1170;
y1_2 = 87.6330;
y2_2 = 216.1425;

% Centroid of line B
c_x_2 = 160.9685;
c_y_2 = 151.8081;


theta1 = atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1);% Angle between line A and x-axis
theta2 = atan2(y2_2-y1_2,x2_2-x1_2); % Angle between line B and x-axis
theta=theta2-theta1; % Angle between line A and line B
% Create rotation matrix
R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];

% Create matrix for coordinate points of line B

x = [x1_2 x2_2];
y = [y1_2 y2_2];
v = [x;y];

% Create matrix for centroid for line B
center = repmat([c_x_2; c_y_2], 1, length(x));

% Shift data points 
s = v - center;

% Rotate
so = R*s;

% Shift back to the desired center of rotation
vo = so + center;

x_rotated = vo(1,:);
y_rotated = vo(2,:);
% make a plot
% Line A
plot( [x1 x2], [y1 y2], 'r')
hold on
% Line B
plot([x1_2 x2_2], [y1_2 y2_2], 'g')
hold on
% Rotate line B at its center
plot(x, y, 'k-', x_rotated, y_rotated, 'm-', c_x_2, c_y_2, 'bo');
axis equal
```

[Line A(red), Line B(green), rotated line B(magenta) should be parallel but it is not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbfVi.png)

Comment: Can you apply the rotation to the two points defining Line B?  Wouldn't that lead to your desired result?

Comment: This is what I did. The coordinates for line B is stored in 'v'. The rotation at its center (Line B) worked but the angle seems to be wrong. I can't find the mistake.

Comment: Are you applying the rotation to the "centroid of a line" or to the two points that define Line B?

Comment: I am applying it to the two points that define line B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theta you are using is the angle between the line A and the x-axis. Then you are rotating line B by that angle theta. This will not give you a line parallel to A.

What you want to do is find the angle between line A and line B, then rotate line B by that amount to get a line parallel to line A.

This can be done in the following way:

```matlab
theta1 = atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1);% Angle between line A and x-axis
theta2 = atan2(y2_2-y1_2,x2_2-x1_2); % Angle between line B and x-axis
theta=theta1-theta2; % Angle between line A and line B
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it worked when I changed the last line to: theta = theta1-theta2.